# <a href = "tel: becomes malform in GAS html service

Tags: google-apps-script, tel

I'm making a simple Web apps using Google Apps Script.
When I wrote as

```
< a href = "tel: telphone no" > telphone no< / a >
```

in template file, the error occurs as below.

```
Invalid script or HTML content: HtmlOutput:4+11 - 28: malformed url tel: telphone no
```

and when I embedded javascript to make html   `< a href = "tel: ...`  ,

tag 'tel:' deleted automatically.

How can I make  `< a href = "tel:`   tag using GAS?

Comment: Please edit your question. You need to be more clear about what you have done, and what you are asking. If you have code examples, include them.

Comment: I edited my question, some portion of my question was invisible because of some "<"

Comment: Ok, so you're trying to put a click-to-dial link into a page. Can you show more of your code? In the small example you have, (A) there is no number, which is a problem, and (B) there are spaces, which are invalid.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of characters that are not allowed in URLs, such as that space between "telephone" and "no".

To avoid such problems when generating a URL in code, make use of `encodeURIComponent()`. See [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).